# Can't remove object in array using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This has been extensively covered here, but none of the solutions seems to be working for me. I'm attempting to remove an object from an array using that object's id. Currently, my Schema is:

```
const scheduleSchema = new Schema({
//unrelated
_id: ObjectId
          shifts: [
            {
              _id: Types.ObjectId,
              name: String,
              shift_start: Date,
              shift_end: Date,
            },
          ],
        });
```

I've tried almost every variation of something like this:

```
.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    {
      $pull: {
        shifts: { _id: new Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
      },
    }
  );
```

**Database:**

[Database Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASQUG.png)

Within these variations, the usual response I've gotten has been either an empty array or null.

I was able slightly find a way around this and accomplish the deletion by utilizing the main _id of the Schema (instead of the nested one:

```
.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: <main _id> },
    { $pull: { shifts: { _id: new Types.ObjectId(<nested _id>) } } },
    { new: true }
  );
```

But I was hoping to figure out a way to do this by just using the nested _id. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using the same value (`req.params.id`) for search the `_id` and `shifts._id`. Is that correct or they are different `_id`'s?. Maybe you are looking for: `{ 'shifts._id': req.params.id }` in your query,

Comment: Just updated. See above. I was previously using the same value but was able to accomplish the removal by utilizing the entry's highest nested _id. I'm still wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this though.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see what you mean. This seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'shifts._id': new Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    {
      $pull: {
        shifts: { _id: new Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  );

Comment: I can add an answer to explain in a better way my comment if you want.

Comment: Yes, please! That would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having currently is you are using the same `_id`.

Using mongo, [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method allows three objects: query, update and options.

- `query` object is the object into collection which will be updated.
- `update` is the action to do into the object (add, change value...).
- `options` different options to add.

Then, assuming you have this collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "shifts": [
      {
        "_id": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you try to look for a document which `_id` is 2, obviously response will be empty [(example)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TYJlaildBG_).

Then, if none document has been found, none document will be updated.

What happens if we look for a document using `shifts._id:2`?
This tells mongo "search a document where `shifts` field has an object with `_id` equals to 2". This query works ok [(example)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DG3-CNnCnHW) but be careful, this returns the WHOLE document, not only the array which match the `_id`.

This **not** return:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "shifts": [
      {
        "_id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using this query mongo returns the ENTIRE document where exists a field called `shifts` that contains an object with an `_id` with value 2. This also include the whole array.

So, with tat, you know why `find` object works. Now adding this to an `update` query you can create the query:

This one to remove all `shifts._id` which are equal to 2.

```
db.collection.update({
  "shifts._id": 2
},
{
  $pull: {
    shifts: {
      _id: 2
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/egeCscEfD6t)

Or this one to remove `shifts._id` if parent `_id` is equal to 1

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1
},
{
  $pull: {
    shifts: {
      _id: 2
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WanFC9LpIb_)